# SPOJ ALPHA CODE

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I was practicing the dynamic programming problem on SPOJ. But I have no idea how to solve this one.

Can anyone please help ME in solving http://www.spoj.pl/problems/ACODE/ problem on SPOJ
Thanks!

> Alice and Bob need to send secret messages to each other and are
>   discussing ways to encode their messages:
>
> Alice: “Let’s just use a very simple code: We’ll assign ‘A’ the code
>   word 1, ‘B’ will be 2, and so on down to ‘Z’ being assigned 26.”
>
> Bob: “That’s a stupid code, Alice. Suppose I send you the word ‘BEAN’
>   encoded as 25114. You could decode that in many different ways!”
>   Alice: “Sure you could, but what words would you get? Other than
>   ‘BEAN’, you’d get ‘BEAAD’, ‘YAAD’, ‘YAN’, ‘YKD’ and ‘BEKD’. I think
>   you would be able to figure out the correct decoding. And why would
>   you send me the word ‘BEAN’ anyway?” Bob: “OK, maybe that’s a bad
>   example, but I bet you that if you got a string of length 5000 there
>   would be tons of different decodings and with that many you would find
>   at least two different ones that would make sense.” Alice: “How many
>   different decodings?” Bob: “Jillions!”
>
> For some reason, Alice is still unconvinced by Bob’s argument, so she
>   requires a program that will determine how many decodings there can be
>   for a given string using her code.
>
> Input
>
> Input will consist of multiple input sets. Each set will consist of a
>   single line of at most 5000 digits representing a valid encryption
>   (for example, no line will begin with a 0). There will be no spaces
>   between the digits. An input line of ‘0’ will terminate the input and
>   should not be processed.
>
> Output
>
> For each input set, output the number of possible decodings for the
>   input string. All answers will be within the range of a 64 bit signed
>   integer.
>
> Example
>
> Input:
>
> 25114 1111111111 3333333333 0
>
> Output:
>
> 6 89 1

Comment: Without dp, you can try as - http://www.kodemonk.com/acode-alphacode/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the left, do the following:

1. Find how many words the sequence can be interpreted as (call that say x[k]) up to this point using a finite number of the values for previous calculated for points along the sequence.
2. Move to the next point.

If you still can't get it, you can take a look at the [Welcome to Code Jam](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=90101#s=p2) problem. It somewhat similar and has readily available explanations for it.

Comment: Thankyou,Can You please explain it a bit?

Comment: I left it vague on purpose. My answer was a general dynamic programming answer. This is a programming competition site after all. If you need more help, you should probably look at that problem I pointed you too. If you look under the Contest Analysis link for that problem, you will find some discussions of how to solve it. Then you should have some idea for how to solve the ACODE problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string of numbers as S, then, there are two cases possible : 
1) only the first digit corresponds to an alphabet
2) the first two digits correspond to an alphabet. BUT, only if the first two digits don't form a number greater than 26.

Let S be of size n. Let f(Si) be the number of strings formed by last i digits. Note that you have to find f(Sn). 
Using the above two rules, you can write a relation as :

If first two digits form a number <= 26 :

*f* ( S<sub>k</sub> ) =  *f* (S<sub>k-1</sub>) +  *f* (S<sub>k-2</sub>)

If first two digits form a number > 26 :

[image: f(S_k) = f(S_{k-1})]